# Setting up mail server in pc

Tags: email, php, mail-server

While I working on a PHP script, sometimes it need to send emails. To see the progress I have to upload the full project online. Is there any way to setting up a mail server in my local machine? I'm using windows 8.

Comment: Do you really want to set-up a local mail server, or you just want your e-mail delivered (e.g., by your ISP)?

Comment: Is it possible sending emails from local machine without mail server?

Comment: @sameerdzn yes just use `phpmailer` class.

Comment: Of course. That's how people sent e-mail before everybody switched to web mail :)

Answer (score 1):

`PHPMailer` is a full featured email transfer Class for PHP supporting SMTP and POP3. So you not need to setup mail server on your pc. It works on localhost too.

**Class Features**

- Probably the world's most popular code for sending email from PHP!
- Used by many open-source projects: Drupal, SugarCRM, Yii, Joomla! and many more
- Integrated SMTP support - **send without a local mail server**
- Send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and REPLY-TOs
- Multipart/alternative emails for mail clients that do not read HTML email
- Support for 8bit, base64, binary, and quoted-printable encoding
- SMTP authentication with LOGIN, PLAIN, NTLM and CRAM-MD5 mechanisms
- Native language support
- Compatible with PHP 5.0 and later
- Much more!

[Githup Repo and more about it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Thank you Vahid. And sorry I can't vote up your answer for my under 15 reputation.

Comment: @sameerdzn maybe next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a STMP Mail class and you can send it for example via Google Mail. No need to upload it on your server then.