# php mail() function : has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, email

Based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537126/php-mail-function-didnt-receive-any-e-mail), I was not receiving any e-mail. And then, I tried to run that on http://writecodeonline.com/.

Finally I got warning notification ([check here](http://sta.sh/0cb4kys8kgy)). Is that the problem why I didn't receive any e-mail?

Comment: Yes it is (15 characters yay)

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: here is full code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537126/php-mail-function-didnt-receive-any-e-mail

Comment: Looks like your server is not properly set for the mail() function

Comment: Your code is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` there is setting for `disable_functions` where server admin can put command/operation which he want to disable for security purpose. so it may be possible mail() function has entry into that..Please check with your php.ini for this setting..for eg `disable_functions=popen,exec,system,passthru,proc_open,shell_exec,show_source,phpinfo,mail`

Comment: I find it, then what should I do?

Comment: You have to remove mail command from that..it may require root permission to do changes in php.ini..so if you do any changes in php.ini on local server (shared server) it will not reflect as it get override by root user php.ini..need to contact root user to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The site says that because they've disabled that method in their `php.ini` file. However, if you wish to make the `mail()` method work, you have to setup it up.

However, I found an answer for you which I found on StackOverflow. You can follow it to accomplish the task. [Setting up mail server in pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443286/setting-up-mail-server-in-pc)

Comment: this is my php.ini setting

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = henrikus.antony@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

but I still didn't receive any e-mail

Comment: If you're doing it on localhost, I don't think it works because even I've tried it before. However, try doing it on an actual host, it should work.

Comment: but I need to send it through localhost. do you have some method for it?

Comment: I've tried but never succeeded man. However, my scripts tend to work on Web Hosts. It's probably because of misconfigured mail stuff in our local servers.

Comment: how about phpmailer? I used that too but the result was same